# Detectar navegador e redirecionar o usuário

Tags: javascript, html, navegador-de-internet

Estou com um problema de animações no Safari e gostaria de saber como restringir o uso do *Safari* de todas as versões sem ter que listar uma por uma, por exemplo se eu fosse redirecionar uma versão do *Internet Explorer* seria:

```
<!--[if IE 7]> <script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.http://browsehappy.com/";
```

Aguardo uma ajuda, obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar um regex para retornar true se for *Safari*.

**Exemplo:**

```
var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
console.log(isSafari);
```

Answer (score 3):

Um método mais completo para identificar qualquer navegador seria com a seguinte função:

```
navigator.sayswho = (function(){
var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem, 
M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*([\d\.]+)/i) || [];
if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
    tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+(\.\d+)?)/g.exec(ua) || [];
    return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
}
M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]:[navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
if((tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
return M.join(' ');
});

//"Chrome 46.0.2490.80"
```

E no seu caso:

```
if (navigator.saywswho().toLowerCase().indexOf("safari") != -1) {
    window.location = "http://google.com/chrome";
}
```