# Como faço para que um script não funcione no navegador Opera?

Tags: html, script, navegador-de-internet, opera

Quero que meu script funcione em todos os navegadores, *exceto* no Opera. O que eu tenho que acrescentar ao meu código para bloquear seu funcionamento no Opera? O script que uso é:

```
<script>
        function openWindow() {
           window.open("banner","_blank","width=400px,height=400px,top=100,left=250");
        }
</script>
```

Comment: não procurei para ver se sua pergunta já foi respondida antes, mas achei [essa aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96571/4816) que acho que pode te ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Opa, seguinte:
   você cria uma variável e atribui o parâmetro "navigator.userAgent", esta variável agora ira deter o as informações do browser.
Veja qual a posição desta informação dentro da String que estará nesta variável inicial.

Use agora o indexOf na variável que contem sua informação de browser atribuindo ela a outra variável ai é só você aplicar um if simples para chamar a function que tu quer ou não.

No meu caso usei um alert no lugar da função e o navegador Firefox pra testar

Boa sorte meu caro....

```
    var browser = navigator.userAgent;
    var qualbrowser = browser.indexOf('Firefox');

    if(qualbrowser > 10){
    alert(qualbrowser);

    }
```